# Adding functionality of controllers to certain view In Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view called 129.html and it's format is like following. It's basically bunch of questions which are reading from json file.

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <h2 ng-bind="group.title"></h2>
        <div class="" ng-repeat="section in group.sections">
            <div class="" ng-repeat="field in section.fields">

                <!-- textfield -->
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form[field.id].$invalid }" ng-if="field.type === 'text'">
                    <!-- <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title.substr(field.title.indexOf('.') + 2)}}</label><br> -->
                    <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.id}}" name="{{field.id}}" ng-model="formData[field.id]" ng-required="field.validations.required" ng-minlength="field.validations.min_length">
                    <p class="form-group-note" ng-if="field.info" ng-bind="field.info"></p>

                    <div ng-show="form.$submitted" ng-cloack>
                        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form['{{field.id}}'].$error.required" ng-if="field.validations.required">Please enter a value, this field is required</span>
                        <span class="help-block" ng-show="form['{{field.id}}'].$error.minlength" ng-if="field.validations.min_length">Please enter a value of at least {{field.validations.min_length}} characters</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Ana I have `MainController.js` which has functionality of saving users' input in localstorage in realtime. However, it seems like my `129.html` is not recognizing that maincontroller.How can I add this to the view? I've seen something like `ng-controller=MainController` but i'm not sure whether this is correct.

Comment: Please provide more details, there is not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a router you can link your controller to the view otherwise the ng-controller directive is a good way to do it.

You cannot associate the "ng-controller" directive with the "ng-repeat" directive because it will call the controller for each group so you need to encapsulate all of it in a parent tag such as a div :

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  (...)
</div>
</div>
```